# Is there a way to build CSS from SASS entirely in the browser?

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp

I know that node-sass and Gulp require a NodeJS runtime to watch and build SASS files.  I'd like to be able to accept SASS as a JavaScript string in my web application, and output CSS as a string, which I can then append to the stylesheet. I need Sass' preprocessing capabilities, but would like to avoid making a round trip every time I change base variables in my .scss file.

Answer (score 0):

> [Sass.js](https://github.com/medialize/sass.js) can do this by Emscripting libSass. A convenience API for compiling Sass via JavaScript

<sub>From [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38472796/is-there-a-way-to-build-css-from-sass-entirely-in-the-browser#comment64349295_38472796) by [ScottL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6443274/scottl)</sub> on Jul 20 '16 at 5:46